# Binding is not changing Button.Content property

Tags: c#, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `Button` in a Template and it's value is bound to `INotifyPropertyChanged` but the `Content` doesn't change at runtime. It only updates it one time. But doesn't change it if I trigger the change from code behind.

As far as I know I have set-up the code absolutely right but I could be wrong somewhere. I trigger the change from the `Flyout` which is shown from the button click but it doesn't change the button content.

My XAML code is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserUploads">
        <UserControl>
            <RelativePanel Name="panel"
                           Margin="5">
                <Image Name="image" 
                       Source="{Binding VideoThumbnail, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding VideoTitle, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Name="title"
                           Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                           MaxLines="2"/>
                <TextBlock Name="publish"
                           Text="{Binding PublishingTime, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Name="privacy"
                           Text="{Binding PrivacyStatus, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button Name="LikeBtn"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                        Click="LikeBtn_Click"
                        Content="{Binding FavoriteBtnContent, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </Button>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="image.Width"
                                        Value="144"/>
                                <Setter Target="image.Height"
                                        Value="81"/>
                                <Setter Target="title.MaxLines"
                                        Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Target="title.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="image"/>
                                <Setter Target="publish.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="title"/>
                                <Setter Target="privacy.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="publish"/>
                                <Setter Target="LikeBtn.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="privacy"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="550"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="image.Width"
                                        Value="256"/>
                                <Setter Target="image.Height"
                                        Value="144"/>
                                <Setter Target="title.MaxLines"
                                        Value="2"/>
                                <Setter Target="title.(RelativePanel.RightOf)"
                                        Value="image"/>
                                <Setter Target="publish.(RelativePanel.RightOf)"
                                        Value="image"/>
                                <Setter Target="privacy.(RelativePanel.RightOf)"
                                        Value="image"/>
                                <Setter Target="publish.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="title"/>
                                <Setter Target="privacy.(RelativePanel.Below)"
                                        Value="publish"/>
                                <Setter Target="LikeBtn.(RelativePanel.RightOf)"
                                        Value="image"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </RelativePanel>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My xaml.cs code-behind is:

```
public sealed partial class UserUploads : Page
{


    public UserUploads()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj;
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        // load data

        // load uploaded videos without live streams
        Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj.VideoUploadsList = await Helpers.APIData.GetUserUploads(Helpers.APIData.VideoType.Uploaded);
        // load uploaded live streams
        Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj.LiveStreamsList = await Helpers.APIData.GetUserUploads(Helpers.APIData.VideoType.Live);
        // load playlists

        // done
    }



    private void LikeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Helpers.UserUploadedVideos)((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
        if (item.LikedOrNot == Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.VideoLike.none)
        {
            var menu1 = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Like" };
            var menu2 = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Dislike" };
            menu1.Click += (s, es) => 
            {
                LikeBtnFlyout_Click(s);
            };
            var panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Children.Add(menu1);
            panel.Children.Add(menu2);
            var flyout = new Flyout() { Content = panel };
            flyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
        }
        else
        {
            var menu1 = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Remove Like/Dislike" };
            menu1.Click += (s, es) => { LikeBtnFlyout_Click(s); };
            var panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Children.Add(menu1);
            var flyout = new Flyout() { Content = panel };
            flyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
        }
    }

    private void LikeBtnFlyout_Click(object sender)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        var item = new Helpers.INotifyProperty();
        if (menuItem.Text == "Like")
        {
            // like the vide
            Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj.FavoriteBtnContent = new FontIcon() { Glyph = Helpers.SettingsKeys.LikeIcon };
        }
        else if (menuItem.Text == "Dislike")
        {
            // dislike the video
            Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj.FavoriteBtnContent = new FontIcon() { Glyph = Helpers.SettingsKeys.DislikeIcon };
        }
        else
        {
            // remove the like/dislike as in "none"
            Helpers.UserUploadedVideos.inotifyObj.FavoriteBtnContent = "Like/Dislike";
        }
    }
}
```

My custom class with `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class UserUploadedVideos : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum VideoLike
    {
        like,
        dislike,
        none
    }

    public static UserUploadedVideos inotifyObj = new UserUploadedVideos();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string setting = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(setting));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UserUploadedVideos> uploadedVideos;
    public ObservableCollection<UserUploadedVideos> VideoUploadsList
    {
        get { return uploadedVideos; }
        set
        {
            if (value != uploadedVideos)
            {
                uploadedVideos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UserUploadedVideos> liveSreams;
    public ObservableCollection<UserUploadedVideos> LiveStreamsList
    {
        get { return liveSreams; }
        set
        {
            if (value != liveSreams)
            {
                liveSreams = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private object btnContent;
    public object FavoriteBtnContent
    {
        get
        {
            if (btnContent == null)
            {
                btnContent = "Like/Dislike";
            }
            return btnContent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != btnContent)
            {
                btnContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private BitmapImage vThumbnail;
    public BitmapImage VideoThumbnail
    {
        get { return vThumbnail; }
        set
        {
            if (value != vThumbnail)
            {
                vThumbnail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string vTitle;
    public string VideoTitle
    {
        get { return vTitle; }
        set
        {
            if (value != vTitle)
            {
                vTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string publishTime;
    public string PublishingTime
    {
        get { return publishTime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != publishTime)
            {
                publishTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string privacyStatus;
    public string PrivacyStatus
    {
        get { return privacyStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (value != privacyStatus)
            {
                privacyStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string vID;
    public string VideoID
    {
        get { return vID; }
        set
        {
            if (value != vID)
            {
                vID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string cID;
    public string ChannelID
    {
        get { return cID; }
        set
        {
            if (value != cID)
            {
                cID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private VideoLike likeOrNot;
    public VideoLike LikedOrNot
    {
        get { return likeOrNot; }
        set
        {
            if (value != likeOrNot)
            {
                likeOrNot = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string pageToken;
    public string PageToken
    {
        get { return pageToken; }
        set
        {
            if (value != pageToken)
            {
                pageToken = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

All the other properties work well as I don't have to change them after the first time but I do need to change the button content whenever I can.

So please help me sort out what is going wrong here. Thanks

**Update:**

I changed the code a little bit and used `x:Bind` with the whole list and tried to update the button from its sender object and it works. I can see the changes instantly if I change the `Button` content from it's sender object.

Comment: have you set the button's Content property _directly_ from somewhere in code behind?

Comment: @elgonzo compiler helps in this case if you use this `[CallerMemberName]` attribute

Comment: @kennyzx, you are right. Also, i was misremembering. null/emtpy string as property name signals all properties will/might have changed their value. Sorry for any confusion :(

Comment: There is a possibility that you set the static `inotifyObj` variable to another UserUploadedVideos object somewhere. Just to make sure that does not happen, change the declaration from `public static UserUploadedVideos inotifyObj` to `public static readonly UserUploadedVideos inotifyObj`

Comment: I think the list doesn't get updated somehow when the button property changes. Idk why is that. It should update itself but it doesn't. I also created a single Button on the page and its property was changing but not inside the listview.